# Make div visible after text input is greater than 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, input

I have created a function for displaying a div when the text length is greater than 2. But it doesn't seem to be working.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bj22met8/

javascript

```
function showDIV(){
 text = document.getElementById("search");
    if (text.length >=1){
        document.getElementById("section").style.visibility = 
  "visible";
    }

  }
```

html

```
<div id="section">
  dsfdsf
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="search" size="20" onkeydown="showDIV();">
```

style

```
 #section{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: `text = document.getElementById("search").value`, to begin with

Comment: This is working code : https://jsfiddle.net/bj22met8/6/

Answer (score 4):

You need to test input value. DOM object (result of `document.getElementById`) has no length.

```
if (text.value.length >= 1) {...}
```

Comment: oh I had the javascript in a different panel not on the html pannel. Thats why it didnt work. Thanks

Comment: @htmlnoob I don't know why it's not working on jsfiddle - you call `showDIV` function which has to be defined first. Don't know how jsfiddle works with scripts in JS tab, but moving above the function call is working. In real you can put JS under the HTML, it will work too.

Comment: I've updated the script to when the text is less than 2 then the div is hidden again. But it doesnt seem to be working. https://jsfiddle.net/bj22met8/2/

Comment: @htmlnoob use keyup instead of keydown + length condition is `> 1` instead of `>= 1`, https://jsfiddle.net/bj22met8/5/

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you for your help.